# NPM - preinstall scripts are being ignored when depedencies or devDependencies are present

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, package.json

I am inside a proxy network, I had to install global dependencies like `gulp` in my package.json, to leverage the pain of switching between proxies, I used preinstall to `npm config set [proxy]` something like

```
{
   "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm config set [proxy]"
   }
   ...
}
```

This works perfectly when there are no dependecies in it. As soon it read there is some dependency say like `gulp`, first thing it does is to go fetch it, and ignores my `preinstall` script.

```
{
   "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm config set [proxy]"
   },
   "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1"
   }
   ...
}
```

Suggest some other way to perform this, I am also planning to host private repositories with outside dependencies, to be consumable by other projects inside our network.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue... seems to me the preinstall hook is not being handled properly

Comment: @JRulle, exactly I am trying to run through all github issues on npm, it says it has been already fixed, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.